# Send AJAX data to node express

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I am trying to send data with AJAX to node express, but as I handled it without express module (with if (req.method="POST"){function on data...})

as I can catch it with express.

NODE code to catch data:() for now nothing happens even in console.log)

```
app.get('/getdata',function(req, res){
  res.send('Something');
});

app.post('/getdata', function (req, res){
  console.log(req.body.objectData);
  res.contentType('json');
  res.send({ some: JSON.stringify({response:'json'}) });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5073);
```

A HTML page with AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#Send').on('click', function () {
    var toSend = $('#Sth').val();
    alert(toSend);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: { objectData: toSend },
      contentType: "application/json",
      cache: false,
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5073/'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <input id="Sth" type="text" name="Content" />
  <div id="select_div"><a href="#" id="select_link">Test</a></div>  
  <div id="test"> Content to be copied</div>
  <input id="Send" type="submit" />
</body>
```

Well, I do not know what to do, please help.

Comment: `'/getdata'` != `'http://127.0.0.1:5073/'`

Comment: Changed to url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5073/getdata'

Still not working.

Comment: Do you have a json body parsing middleware (e.g. [`bodyParser.json()`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)) being `use()`d somewhere before that `app.post('/getdata', ...);` route?

Comment: I have this before app.post...

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

Comment: Firstly, check ajax.done or ajax.error and then write result plz

Comment: Yep, after adding error and success, I get Error Msg :/
So Ajax doesnt work, strange...

Comment: Try this??? http.createServer(app).listen([Your Port]);

Comment: And then I need your ajax error message. $ajax(...).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

   WE.F.alert("connecting server failed.");
   console.log(errorThrown);
  });

Answer (score 0):

Care to give this a shot?

```
app.post('/endpoint', function(req, res){
    var obj = {};
    console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

https://gist.github.com/diorahman/1520485